# Sort a list based on the sort indexes of another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists and I want to sort the one of them (`scores`) in reverse order and get the corresponding indexes in order to sort the second one (`section_id`).

For example:

```
section_id = [5, 6, 8, 14]
scores = [4, 11, 13, 7]
```

The new lists will be:

```
sorted_reverse_scores = [13, 11, 7, 4]
sorted_section_id = [8, 6, 14, 5]
```

Do you know how to achieve this?

Currently the only thing I do is:

```
sorted_reverse_scores = section_id.sort(reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
section_id  = [5, 6, 8, 14]
scores  = [4, 11, 13, 7]
sorted_reverse_scores =[]
sorted_section_id =[]
for i in sorted(zip(scores,section_id),reverse=True):
  sorted_reverse_scores.append(i[0])
  sorted_section_id.append(i[1])
print(sorted_reverse_scores)
print(sorted_section_id)
```

> output
>
> [13, 11, 7, 4]
>   [8, 6, 14, 5]

Comment: don't dump the code put some explaination

Comment: My initial lists are `section_id` `and scores`. I want to get the `sorted_section_id` based on the `sorted_reverse_scores`.

Comment: I corrected the answer you can validate now @zinon